What serde format should I use to serialize a Hashmap keyed by [u8;32]?
I have data structure I want to save to disk.  Just the holdings collection.  SsStock is another struct.  Currently I'm trying to endoce to cbor which gives a compile time error:
  #[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
  struct SsHolding {
      shares: f64,
      stock: SsStock,
  }
  pub struct Client {
      ...
      holdings: collections::HashMap<[u8;32], SsHolding>,
  }

  fn save_holdings(&self, writer: impl io::Write) -> Result<(), MyError> {
      cbor::Encoder::from_writer(writer).encode(&self.holdings)?;
      Ok(())
  }

I get:
error[E0277]: the trait bound `SsHolding: rustc_serialize::serialize::Decodable`
 is not satisfied                                                               
   --> src/lib.rs:323:18                
    |                                                                           
323 |                 .collect::<Result<_, _>>()?;                              
    |                  ^^^^^^^ the trait `rustc_serialize::serialize::Decodable`
 is not implemented for `SsHolding`, which is required by `DecodedItems<'_, BufReader<impl io::Read>, _>: Iterator`                                             
    |                                                                           
    = help: the following other types implement trait `rustc_serialize::serialize::Decodable`: ...

    = note: required for `([u8; 32], SsHolding)` to implement `rustc_serialize::
serialize::Decodable`
    = note: required for `DecodedItems<'_, BufReader<impl io::Read>, ([u8; 32], 
SsHolding)>` to implement `Iterator`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `SsHolding: rustc_serialize::serialize::Decodable`
 is not satisfied
   --> src/lib.rs:322:18
    |
322 |                 .decode()
    |                  ^^^^^^ the trait `rustc_serialize::serialize::Decodable` 
is not implemented for `SsHolding`, which is required by `([u8; 32], SsHolding):
 rustc_serialize::serialize::Decodable`

I started trying to serialize to csv, but my struct with nested Vecs isn't representable by the csv encoder.
I tried json, but I got a runtime error with that, about map keys need to be Strings.  Which is fair enough if the json spec specifies that.
Tried cbor, with the results above.
(Back when Holdings was a Vec instead of HashMap<[u8;32], SsHolding>, it was serializing to csv, with some custom #[serde(deserialize_with = "path")] field attributes.  However it wasn't easy to make that work well due to limitations in the csv format.  Using json, it worked until I introduced the map based on the bytes key.)
Changing back to json:
  fn save_holdings(&self, writer: impl io::Write) -> Result<(), MyError> {
      serde_json::to_writer(writer, &self.holdings)?;
      Ok(())
  }

It compiles, but I get an error at runtime: Error: Data(Error("key must be a string", line: 0, column: 0))
Other than trial and error going through all the Data formats at https://serde.rs/, can someone give me a hint as to which format may be able to serialize my data?

The issue with the cbor crate is that it isn't a serde format. It uses rustc-serialize, which is the old precursor to serde. cbor is a very old crate. You either need a format that can represent the serde forms of your types as-is, or you need to adapt your types to work in the format. Serde has a list of formats you can try in their docs.

If you want your question to survive, you should edit it down to something like "How do I serialize HashMap<[u8;32], _> to CBOR?"

Thanks to the hint from drewtato, it turned out I was using the wrong crate.  Once I used the correct crate (ciborium vs. cbor), it worked fine.
        pub fn save_holdings(&self, writer: impl io::Write) -> Result<(), MyError> {
            ciborium::into_writer(&self.holdings, writer)?;
            Ok(())
        }
        pub fn load_holdings(&mut self, reader: impl io::Read) -> Result<(),MyError> {
            self.holdings = ciborium::from_reader(reader)?;
            Ok(())
        }

The cbor crate is an older crate that does not use serde at all, so serde's #[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)] doesn't help make my struct serializeable with cbor.
